# Save Image as a combination of two layers

Tags: android, camera, imageview, frame, surfaceview

I am trying to make a camera app with custom frames. My layout is as follows...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- Place the objects you want on the bottom here -->

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- Objects that should be on top of the SurfaceView -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pictureFrame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/frame" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFrame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Change Frame" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSnap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Take Photo" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java code is laid out as follows...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        snap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSnap);
        snap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO take a photo, combine the Frame Layer with the camera
                // preview to produce a single jpeg. Once a photo has been
                // taken, show it to the user and give them sharing options
                camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback,  myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);

            }
        });

    }
    ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Bitmap bitmapPicture=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Uri uriTarget= getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
            OutputStream imageFileOS;
            try{
                imageFileOS=getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            camera.startPreview();

        }

    };

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        if(previewing){
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing=false;
        }

        if(camera!=null){
            try{
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing=true;
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera=Camera.open();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;
        previewing=false;
    }
}
```

At the moment I can only save what is in the surfaceview without the frame. Is it possible to save the image as a combination of the SurfaceView and the ImageView? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the SurfaceView is receiving the preview, but the captured camera image is arriving as JPEG data.  So the contents of the SurfaceView don't really matter.  Can you just render the received camera image to a bitmap, render whatever you have in the ImageView on top of that, and then save the result?

Comment: @genius have u done your task or found any solution of your question ?